# NS2 : How to know the number of channel slots?

Tags: channel, ns2, timeslots

This is regarding `NS2` `MAC` layer simulation.

Suppose that the `Ns2` Channel bandwidth is `1 Mbps`.

Then, by default, into how many slots is the channel divided into?

If it is divided, how much is each individual slot?

And what does this line  `mac->phymib_.getSlotTime()` give?

Answer (score 0):

`mac->phymib_.getSlotTime()` returns the duration of a `slot`, which is a parameter of the [Distributed Coordination Function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distributed_Coordination_Function) (DCF), of the 802.11 MAC protocol.

Re: `how many slots is the channel divided into.`

I think your are confusing the `802.11 MAC` with `TDMA`.

If you are interested in simulating `TDMA` in `ns2`, you should check out the files `mac/mac-tdma.cc` and `mac/mac-tdma.h`. Unfortunately, no example script for `TDMA` is given with the allinone-package.

Answer (score 0):

Talking about channel slots I assume you are asking about Mac/Tdma wireless protocol (specify otherwise):

Curving into the source codes:

**from tdma-mac.cc:**

```
//Get the parameters of the link (which in bound in mac.cc, 2M by default),
//the packet length within one TDMA slot (1500 byte by default), 
//and the max number of nodes (64) in the simulations.

// Max data length allowed in one slot (byte)
#define MAC_TDMA_MAX_DATA_LEN 1500        

// How many time slots in one frame.
#define MAC_TDMA_SLOT_NUM       32
```

Also default bandwidth of wireless links is defined in ns-default.tcl along with some other values:

```
Phy/WirelessPhy set bandwidth_ 2e6

Mac/Tdma set slot_packet_len_   1500
Mac/Tdma set max_node_num_  64
```